# Rails website documentation for an older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails has beautiful documentation on their guides and their website: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I am taking on an application that uses Rails 2.2.2 but the documentation on the rails site is for the latest version.  How could I find the 2.2.2 documentation?

In other words check out how Django does it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//  You can click which version it is and the documentation will adjust accordingly?

I do see that RailsBrain.com has an previous release docs, but they only display the API and I am looking for the nice site(ie. how current release site looks but for 2.2.2)

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ has a version scale to see documentation for different versions.

Also official guides have branches for any older versions, e.g. Rails 2.3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/, Rails 3.2: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/

Comment: Yup, apidock is really great to browse code documentation. Anyways they guides are much easier to read if you are looking for overviews of the framework features.

Comment: I'm not sure apidock is maintained any more, certainly the activity thread isn't (it's currently mostly porn spam).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

http://railsguides.heroku.com/

It's a collection of the guides of each version.

Btw, Its old one is based on 2.3.5 but it will be much easier than reading the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an offline solution, I strongly recommend [Dash.app](http://kapeli.com/dash) -for Mac OS- and [Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/). -for Windows & Ubuntu- By downloading docsets you'd like, you can start using API docs offline.